# Adding a Command Argument to a DropDownList nested in a Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

Is it possible to add to a DropDownList Control nested in a Listview a Command Argument?
I want it to execute a function if the selected index is changed.

Comment: Is implementing the DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event for the DDL nested in the ListView not suitable for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You may implement you own control derived from the DropDownList and implement IButtonControl interface on it.

Comment: The attached link is now dead. This is the exact reason why it is suggested to include code in the answer!